# Как сделать exe-файл из java-файла?

Tags: eclipse, exe, java, классы

Пишу в Eclipse на Java. Надо сделать exe-шник простенькой программы. Как это сделать в виндовс хр?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот [как сделать exe из jar в eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse), используется утилита [Launch4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/files/launch4j-3/3.1.0-beta1/) (бесплатная, с открытым кодом).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [Jar2Exe](http://www.jar2exe.com)