# Как сделать в Eclipse приложение для Windows (*.exe) на Java?

Tags: exe, java

Как сделать в Eclipse приложение для Windows (*.exe) на Java, которое будет выглядеть, как обычное приложение, работающие с формами (как в том же Visual Studio, или C++ Builder)?

П. С. Делаю приложение, которое связывает телефон с компом. Как в Eclipse делать для телефона, я уже давно понял. А вот как для компа - непонятно.

Comment: [ Вот как.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/301174#301203) Да и кстати, если ты думаешь, что, преобразовав свою прогу в .exe, ты избавишься от потребоности устанавливать JRE на свой комп, я тебя огорчу.

Comment: Правильно, огорчайте ТС, т.к. от подобных вещей типа "Eclipse и exe" глаза при чтении вытекают на клавиатуру...

---
И, кстати, плюс за то, что редиректите туда, откуда тоже придется редиректнуться. В следующий раз на подобные вопросы, лично я, буду приводить ссылку на ваш ответ ;)

Comment: @0xFFh угу, этим заодно выучат, что такое стак трейсы

Comment: @vasyasgors, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).